# How to use properties from OSGI/Karaf ConfigurationAdminService with Spring dependency injection

Tags: spring, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I am trying to inject properties stored in Karaf into my Camel/Spring-Service. So far i tried to inject the properties the way documented in [Fuse documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/DeployCamel-OsgiConfigProps.html) and [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/compendium.html).
But both seem outdated: the `osgix:cm-properties` can't be parsed by current Spring version (Fuse 6.3 uses 3.2.16).

On the other hand Apache Aries seem to have something that could be used now. The `aries-blueprint-spring` feature contains two bundles:

- aries.blueprint.spring
- aries.blueprint.spring.extender

I found an old user-list post that points to this bundles. But i can't find any documentation or example using this. We only need to inject the properties.

Answer (score 3):

Have been using OSGi Service Compendium for sometime now and below is some extract from one of my projects, hope it helps.

Important is the declaration of **compendium** namespace and it's prefix **osgix**

Also note the declaration of **persistent-id** as the same has to be defined in Karaf configuration file to be created inside etc directory of your container instance.

Now there is Spring **property-placeholder** referring to osgix properties declaration and **propertyPlaceholder** inside CamelContext. Both are required if you want to access properties outside - ${propName} and inside - {{propName}} CamelContext.

> To access properties outside Camel Context syntax is **${propertyName}**
>   To access properties inside Camel Context syntnax is **{{propertyName}}**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:osgix="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"   xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring               http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



    <!-- A. Configuration Management -->
    <osgix:cm-properties id="cachingServicesProp" persistent-id="com.fsafrica.cachingservices.cm">
        <prop key="amqBrokerUrl">tcp://localhost:61616</prop>
        <prop key="amqUsername">admin</prop>
        <prop key="amqPassword">admin</prop>
        <prop key="queueName">jms/SRK_CACHE_QUEUE</prop>
    </osgix:cm-properties>

    <!-- Required for resolving properties for Beans outside CamelContext -->
    <ctx:property-placeholder properties-ref="cachingServicesProp" />



    <!-- B. ActiveMQ -->
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" id="activemq">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${amqBrokerUrl}" />
        <property name="userName" value="${amqUsername}" />
        <property name="password" value="${amqPassword}" />
    </bean>



    <camelContext id="CC-CachingMain" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <!-- Required for resolving properties inside CamelContext -->
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="ref:cachingServicesProp"/>



        <!-- JMS INTERFACE -->
        <route id="Route-JMSMasterData">

            <from uri="activemq:queue:{{queueName}}?transacted=false" />

            <log message="#### After putting some data in the Queue (jms/SRK_CACHE_QUEUE) you should be able read this text on Karaf console" />

        </route>

    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: thanks, but i did is exactly this way. The problem is that on runtime spring can't parse the xml. It seems that current spring versions dropped support for this stuff?!